# Google Maps API Error with no changes in the page code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Today, with no changes in our code, Google Maps is not working, we are getting this errors today:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
at js?key=api_key:102
at js?key=api_key:103
at Fa (js?key=api_key:26)
at js?key=api_key:101
at js?key=api_key:141
(anonymous) @ js?key=api_key:102
(anonymous) @ js?key=api_key:103
Fa @ js?key=api_key:26
(anonymous) @ js?key=api_key:101
(anonymous) @ js?key=api_key:141
search?v=_I0tOw3rSQ_doWiefjlY5aQCOGyEGSTSZnF3_H-NxWg1:1 

Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.LatLngBounds is not a constructor
at a (search?v=_I0tOw3rSQ_doWiefjlY5aQCOGyEGSTSZnF3_H-NxWg1:1)
at Object.d [as init] (search?v=_I0tOw3rSQ_doWiefjlY5aQCOGyEGSTSZnF3_H-NxWg1:1)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (search?v=_I0tOw3rSQ_doWiefjlY5aQCOGyEGSTSZnF3_H-NxWg1:1)
at l (jquery?v=7Sd5PfzIDKXEDPMwZrZ0oOZN3B1M8lJMYBbJRNRKggY1:1)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery?v=7Sd5PfzIDKXEDPMwZrZ0oOZN3B1M8lJMYBbJRNRKggY1:1)
at Function.ready (jquery?v=7Sd5PfzIDKXEDPMwZrZ0oOZN3B1M8lJMYBbJRNRKggY1:1)
at HTMLDocument.ht (jquery?v=7Sd5PfzIDKXEDPMwZrZ0oOZN3B1M8lJMYBbJRNRKggY1:1)
```

We are loading the API like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=pt-PT"></script>
```

We did not change anything in the page and today when we try the page, nothing is working.

Any idea? Did Google changed anything between yesterday and today?

Comment: @geocodezip Hi, it stopped again today and there is nothing to seems to solve the issue! Help please!

Comment: Apparently there was a new release overnight although this is not yet reflected in the release notes. Try loading a previous API version (`v=3.30`) as per the instructions you were already given above, and see if it works.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Hi thank! I have found the issue (answer below). It was related with the use of the word Map in my library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the "experimental" version of the API, try the release version.  Details (from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)):

> The current release version is 3.29. You can request it with either of the following bootstraps:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3
    &key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

or

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29
    &key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

related question: [Google Maps API: Load specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416195/google-maps-api-load-specific-version)

Comment: Hi! I had the same problem today with "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3
    &key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap", do you know why this happened?

Comment: A new version of the API was released.  The frozen version is now v3.29, the experimental version is now v3.31.  If you want the frozen version, request it by number or use v=3.0; note that this will only be available until the next release, at which point you won't be able to get that version any more.

Comment: Do I need to be aware of every new version? Or there is a way to play safe?

Comment: Yes (you need to be aware of every new version), that is the way the v3 APIs work.  The "safe" way is to always used the released version (v=3), and test periodically with the experimental version so you can fix errors due to updates before they hit the release version.  Keep an eye on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify for updates.

Comment: I was using v=3, but today, without changing anything, I had all the errors again. To solve the problem, I had to change from v=3 and put v=3.29, so it seems that v=3 it's not the safe mode anymore.

Comment: v=3 is now equivalent to v=3.30 due to the new release.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the v3.30 has some serious changes compared with 3.29 I need to check.

Comment: Hi, I am having problems today again and nothing seems to work with any version! help!

Comment: To people having this issue after Feb 13th 2018: This is a workaround, and will not work after the last rollout. The other Answer by @Patrick solves the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution to the problem based on this [Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined in http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205609/cannot-read-property-entries-of-undefined-in-http-maps-googleapis-com-maps-a) and on @ajayel answer's: "Google changed their Maps API script and started using the variable Map which broke our site November 2017. Renaming the Map variable to OurMap fixed the issue for us."

The issue here is that we was also using the name Map for our main map operations  javascript library, we changed it, and everything started to work fine!

Comment: You should use `var map` instead of `var Map` as per javascript coding standards.

Comment: I use the Module Patern https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/ and all my modules starts with a cap (Map). But I changed to another name now :)

Comment: Map is a global object in EcmaScript 6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. You shouldn't use a custom object with a same name in your code. The same is valid for Symbol. New version of Google Maps JavaScript API relies on ES6 objects.

Comment: @xomena I will consider it in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of error codes, errors and warnings. An error indicates a severe issue which occurred while loading the Google Maps JavaScript API. Your page cannot load the API correctly, and the API will not work on that page. A warning is a supplemental message about the loading of the Google Maps JavaScript API. The warning describes the possible reasons for an error, or suggests potential issues in your code that loads the Google Maps JavaScript API. If you receive only warnings without any errors, the API will work correctly on that page. But we recommend that you fix the potential issues as well.