# Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined in http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Everything worked and suddenly there was a mistake `Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined` that it could be ? (including googlemaps api)

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
    at js?key=<API_KEY>&callback=Map.init:105`

Map.init

```
    Map.init = function (id) {
    id = id || 'map';
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
        center: {lat: 46.409998, lng: 30.710000},
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoom: this.address ? 20 : 12
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
        var zoom = map.getZoom();
        if (zoom > zoomShowPoints && !pointsVisibility) {
            pointsVisibility = true;
            points.forEach(function (item) {
                item.setVisible(pointsVisibility);
            });
        } else if (zoom <= zoomShowPoints && pointsVisibility) {
            pointsVisibility = false;
            points.forEach(function (item) {
                item.setVisible(pointsVisibility);
            });
        }
    });

    getUsers();
};
```

Comment: Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So that you can understand **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**

Comment: You need to add the code related to the problem. The error is that you are trying to read the property `entries` from an object or something, but in the there's no reference to `entries` anywhere in the code that you shared. I'd recommend you to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I know why he didn't add the code: this error is happening in the https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js endpoint; so it seems to be a Google Maps issue. It's happening to me right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Error with no changes in the page code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192445/google-maps-api-error-with-no-changes-in-the-page-code)

Comment: Problen was in the name of the variable I used. The name of variable was "var Map", so i changed the name and error has gone

Answer (score 9):

Google changed their Maps API script November 2017.  They started using global variable Map which broke our site.  Renaming the Map variable to OurMap in our script fixed the issue.

```
var Map;
```

changes to;

```
var OurMap;
```

Answer (score 3):

it was solved by adding version param

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**v=3**&key=&callback=Map.init

Comment: Not working anymore. Make sure you do not use global variables that are used by google maps. In my case it was 'Map' variable