# Google Maps API: Load specific version

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I try to load a specific version of the Maps API, lets say this one: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.28` and log the version with `console.log(google.maps.version)`, I get **version 3.29.14b**.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7xsxg4cv/.

Even stranger to me is the behaviour in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c15sfj21/.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know there is a `v3.28`? Looks like the server is just rounding the provided version to the nearest valid version.

Comment: Version 3.28 is the actual frozen version https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.28/reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/KlGOnEB4SMs

> We will be making the current experimental version (3.30) the new
>   release version on or shortly after **November 21th, 2017**. The versions
>   will then be:
>
> Experimental: 3.31
>
> Release: 3.30
>
> **Frozen: 3.29**
>
> **3.28 will be deprecated** and you will be served an existing version if you try to request it.

---

The docs aren't updated yet. Looks like the most up to day source of releases is this forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the API has been released (or is in the process of being released), making v3.29 the frozen version and v3.31 the experimental version.

The documentation sometimes takes some time to update.

```js
onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = "Experimental Version=" + google.maps.version;
  alert("Experimental Version:" + google.maps.version);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="version"></div>
```