# Unable to get property 'entries' of undefined or null reference

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does anyone encountered this error message? This only occurs using IE specifically version 11.
[Google Maps API Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bTqF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added version on the version on the js reference.

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29&
        key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

See below post for more information.

[Google Maps API Error with no changes in the page code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192445/google-maps-api-error-with-no-changes-in-the-page-code)